# When are asynchronous functions executed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The functions Gamer1 and Gamer2 repeat the game 6 out of 49 until the game is won. Both functions are executed asynchronously and return Task. In which line are the functions started? According to my observation, they are already started with simulations.Add(Gamer1(rand));. But this should not be the case.

```
namespace simulations{
    public class Program{
        //Methods whose signature contains async, can implements the await keyword.
        static async Task Main(){    
            string input="start";
            List<Task<string>> simulations = new List<Task<string>>();
            // Objects of Rendom Class generates equally distributed random numbers.
            Random rand= new Random();
            
            while(input!="exit"){
                Console.WriteLine("choose an option:");
                Console.WriteLine("1 add lotto player 1");
                Console.WriteLine("2 add lotto player 2");
                Console.WriteLine("3 start lotto simulation");
                Console.WriteLine("4 exit.");
                input=Console.ReadLine();
            
                switch(input){
                    case "1":
                        simulations.Add(Gamer1(rand));
                    break;
                    case "2":
                        simulations.Add(Gamer2(rand));
                    break;
                    case "3":
                        while (simulations.Any())
                        {
                            Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(simulations);
                            string result = await finishedTask;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            simulations.Remove(finishedTask);
                        }
                    
                    break;
                    default:input="exit";break;
                }     
            }
        }  

        static async Task<string> Gamer1(Random rand){
              List<int> lottotipp=new List<int>{12,43,2,13,23,40};
              lottotipp.Sort();
              ulong countTries=1;
              List<int> urne= new List<int>();
              for(int i=0; i<49; i++){urne.Add(i+1);}
              List<int> drawing=new List<int>();
              return await Task.Run(() =>
                    { 
                        while(!drawing.SequenceEqual(lottotipp)){
                            drawing.Clear();
                            int limit=50;
                            for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
                                int randomindex=rand.Next(1,limit-1);
                                int draw=urne[randomindex];
                                drawing.Add(draw);
                                urne.Remove(urne[randomindex]);
                                limit--;
                            }
                            countTries++;
                            drawing.Sort();
                            urne.Clear();
                            for(int i=0; i<49; i++){urne.Add(i+1);}
                        }
                        return $"Lotto player 1 won. He has requiered {countTries} tries. The winning numbers are: {drawing[0]}, {drawing[1]}, {drawing[2]}, {drawing[3]}, {drawing[4]} and {drawing[5]}";

                    } );
            }

            static async Task<string> Gamer2(Random rand){
                List<int> lottotipp=new List<int>{34,19,3,27,40,41};
                lottotipp.Sort();
                ulong countTries=1;
                List<int> urne= new List<int>();
                for(int i=0; i<49; i++){urne.Add(i+1);}
                List<int> drawing=new List<int>();
                return await Task.Run(async () =>
                    { 
                        while(!drawing.SequenceEqual(lottotipp)){
                            drawing.Clear();
                            int limit=50;
                            for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
                                int randomindex=rand.Next(1,limit-1);
                                int draw=urne[randomindex];
                                drawing.Add(draw);
                                urne.Remove(urne[randomindex]);
                                limit--;
                            }
                            countTries++;
                            drawing.Sort();
                            urne.Clear();
                            for(int i=0; i<49; i++){urne.Add(i+1);}
                        }
                        return $"Lotto player 2 won. He has requiered {countTries} tries. The winning numbers are: {drawing[0]}, {drawing[1]}, {drawing[2]}, {drawing[3]}, {drawing[4]} and {drawing[5]}";

                    } );
            }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they started in line `simulations.Add(...)` because you actually call the function in this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to my observation, they are already started with `simulations.Add(Gamer1(rand));`

Yes, async methods return already started tasks (sometimes they called "hot"), so `Gamer1(rand)` call will result in starting the processing (method will execute everything before `Task.Run`, schedule the lambda on the thread pool and will return control to the caller due to `await`).

It is quite recommended that if method returns a `Task` it should be already started. There are ways to create a not-started task [but returning them as is from method is not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#task-status):

> If a TAP method internally uses a task's constructor to instantiate the task to be returned, the TAP method must call Start on the Task object before returning it.

If you want to represent a delayed started task in the code I would recommend to look into something like [`Func<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-7.0) or maybe [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-7.0). For example something along these lines:

```cs
List<Func<Task<string>>> simulations = new();

// while
switch (input)
{
    case "1":
        simulations.Add(() => Gamer1(rand));
        break;
    case "2":
        simulations.Add(() => Gamer2(rand));
        break;
    case "3":
        // start tasks:
        var sims = simulations.Select(func => func()).ToList();
        while (sims.Any())
        {
            Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(sims);
            string result = await finishedTask;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            sims.Remove(finishedTask);
        }

        break;
    default:
        input = "exit";
        break;
}
```